# Distinguishing left and right shift keys in Processing 3

Tags: java, input, processing, keyevent

Alright, I'll say in advance I'm aware this isn't a new concept... But no matter what I research nothing seems to work. Basically, I want to be able to sense every key on my keyboard including the different shift/ctrl/alt/enter keys. Every key besides these returns a unique keyCode which is good, but I can't seem to distinguish these duplicates.

Without any modifications, the `void keyPressed ()` will work just fine. I'm told that to distinguish the duplicate keys I can `import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;` and then use

```
void keyPressed (KeyEvent e) {
  if (keyCode == SHIFT) {
    int location = e.getKeyLocation ();
    if (location == KEY_LOCATION_RIGHT) {
      RShift = true;
    }
    if (location == KEY_LOCATION_LEFT) {
      LShift = true;
    }
  }
}
```

However, some problems arise with this:

- If I import the library, `keyPressed ()` never gets called at all.
- If I import the library but take out the KeyEvent parameter in `keyPressed ()` it works as long as I comment out any reference to the nonexistent KeyEvent e.
- If I DON'T import it and leave the parameter it just complains that `getKeyLocation ()` doesn't exist, but that's it.

Do I need like a reverse override or something?? Help is much appreciated!

P.S. Another related question, how can I distinguish more than left, center, and right mouse buttons? I can get these and the scrollwheel but any other button just returns a mouseButton code of 0. Suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

https://processing.org/reference/keyPressed_.html

The keyPressed() function is called once every time a key is pressed. The key that was pressed is stored in the key variable.

if you want to override keyPressed you must use the same signature so no parameters, in the method you can reference the key variable of the PApplet

like this i believe

void keyPressed ()
**int location = key

edit: int location = keyEvent

Comment: "if you want to override keyPressed you must use the same signature so no parameters, in the method you can reference the key variable of the PApplet" Can you explain this? If I just use the key variable or even keyCode it just returns the same value for both shift keys.

Comment: ok had to go back to the code keyEvent variable of PApplet should do the trick,

Comment: Sorry but, how does one use PApplet? I've never heard of it and from what I'm seeing it's just something to include when making a Processing project within another IDE like Eclipse. What's it got to do with this if I'm using the default Processing IDE?

Comment: from what you said i guess that you are working on a class that extends PApplet

Comment: That's what I'm guessing... So, now what...? Any explanation/fix for the weird behavior?

Comment: i googled this https://forum.processing.org/one/topic/the-shift-keys.html doesnt keyEvent really works?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/130366/discussion-between-squirt-5432-and-j-dev).